# Performance of native stack vs virtual stacks on the heap

Tags: recursion, heap-memory, stack-memory

When doing recursive computations, the most simple solution usually uses function level recursion based on the native stack of the process.

However, sometimes the information stored in every recursion is quite small (lets say, some bytes). The overhead for function calls and native stack frames (eg. as maintained by the C standard runtime) may be high. On the other hand, many stack operations are optimized even to the CPU hardware level. Maintaining a self made stack on the heap requires additional operations of course.

Are there any general rules one can use to decide when an recursion would run faster using the native stack, and when it would be better to use a loop and a selfmade heap based stack (using arrays in the C case for example) ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there're no such rules. It's unlikely that there is a significant difference between native and virtual stacks, cause in both cases allocation/deallocation is the add/sub of the pointer to the top of the stack, i.e., in fact, of the register.

If you think about the convenience of writing and understanding the code, native stack looks better, cause the code is easier. However, there are situations when it's necessary to do your own implementation. F.e. if objects on the stack are very large, or if the algorithm requires two or more stacks.

Otherwise I would prefer the native stack.